# What kind of design of experiment should I choose?

Tags: modeling, experiment-design

In my research, I want to study the early detection of learning problems of students in introductory programming courses. The first part of the study involves collecting their code, submitted to an automatic testing system, and manually analyzing the data searching for categories of problems, e.g. syntactic errors.

This first part will last one year, which is how long the course lasts. For this reason, this population of students cannot be used to evaluate the final result of the study, which is an automatic system to detect learning problems through their code.

Therefore, I need to use the system in another population, even though it will have been built using data from the first population. Is there a design of experiment to do this correctly? Is there anything I need to change in the way I describe my study, so it is correctly described?

Comment: Good question, but I'm not sure if something similar has already been asked. To me it's not yet clear how you want to quantify numerically the categories. Especially since an uncertainty should be accounted for, as well as maybe something like of degree or severity of "learning problem". As soon as you have a handle on this, you could train and validate on the same data, but split into different and disjoint partitions.

Comment: This is a classical Bayesian approach where you start from an originally non-informative scenario, update your information based on your first student population and gain a posterior distribution from that. This posterior can then again be used as a prior distribution for any further student population(s) to come.

Comment: @cherub I wasn't clear on how the categories worked. The categories of problems either exist or not. For example, by analyzing certain things present in the code, there is a "variable declaration" problem when the student has written something such as "3.14 = pi" in their code, or "type comprehension" problem when they use incompatible types in operations.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @alex2006. I'll read about the Bayesian approach to see how it can be applied to my study.

Comment: @AntonioJunior: do you have predefined categories? Maybe binary: has/has not? Are you trying to find correlations? I'm a bit confused now about the original question.

Comment: @cherub I am trying to create categories, these are the categories that the data has revealed so far. When I said "manually analyzing the data searching for categories of problems", I meant these categories. And, yes, they are binary.